# How to record timing for keypress event?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to build a small script that shows, on call back, when I press key <kbd>q</kbd> then after one second I press <kbd>w</kbd> it should show <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd> obviously, **BUT** When, I press <kbd>q</kbd> and then <kbd>w</kbd> not at the same time, just in less than one second, it should show other single character for ex: <kbd>x</kbd> and this is where I am stuck currently **[JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xstBM/16/)** or my full code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(e){
        var text = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
                 
         switch(text){
         case 81:
            text = 'q';
            break;
        case 87:
            text = 'w';
            break; 
 }
    
    if(text == 8){
        
        var str = document.getElementById("out").innerHTML;
        var foo = str.substring(0, str.length -1);
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = foo; 
    }else {
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += text;
    }

    }
        
</script>
   <input  type='text'  onkeyup='check(event);' id='in' />
<div id='out' ></div>
```

I am new to JavaScript, and I am lost as to what lets you record one key press then wait to listen if there is another one existing even inside a second. I have tried also,  `setInterval()` function, but that only executes a function by amount of time it is given.

Comment: Is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aswgM/1/) what you need?

Comment: Yes, and no. @Teemu because, when you press `q` and `w` inside one second, it shows `qx` instead of just `x`. can you pls check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
var timer = new Date(),
    previousChar;

function check (e) {
    var foo,
        text = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode,
        out = document.getElementById('out'),
        str = out.innerHTML;
    switch (text) {
        case 81: text = 'q'; break;
        case 87: text = 'w'; break;
    }
    if (new Date() - timer < 1000 && text === 'w' && previousChar === 'q') {
        text = 'x';
        out.innerHTML = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
    }   
    if (text === 8) {
        foo = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        out.innerHTML = foo; 
    } else {
        out.innerHTML += text;
    }
    previousChar = text;    
    timer = new Date();
    return;
}
```

A live demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aswgM/3/).

---

**EDIT**

Since you've added some more requirements via the comments, here's an edited code for the task:

```
var timer = new Date(),
    keyCombinations = {
        ae: 'ä',
        oe: 'ö',
            qw: 'x'
    };

function check(e){
    var text, str, previousKeys,
        key = e.keyCode || e.charCode,
        out = document.getElementById('out');

    text = String.fromCharCode(key);
    str = out.innerHTML + text;
    previousKeys = str.substring(str.length - 2, str.length);
    if (new Date() - timer < 1000) {
        if (previousKeys in keyCombinations) {
            str = str.substring(0, str.length - 2) + keyCombinations[previousKeys];
        }
    }
    out.innerHTML = str;
    timer = new Date();
    return;
}
```

**Notice, that this code is for `onkeypress` event.** It's more reliable when creating characters from keycodes. You can assign a separate eventhandling for the special keys, like <kbd>backspace</kbd>, within `onkeyup` handler function.

This is not a perfect code, but it gives you an idea, how to implement this task. It uses an object literal to store all key combinations and their replacements. This way you don't need to write any loop at all.

A live example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aswgM/8/).

Comment: This is the BEST answer ever... One question, I am trying to change over 200 characters, just like `qw` shows `x` there are over 200 like `qw` which will echo another characters, so my question is is there anyway minimize the code, rather than creating `if (new Date() - timer < 1000 && text === 'w' && previousChar === 'q') {
        text = 'x';` 200 times

Comment: @kranzdot This code is only for a very special case, like yours in the question. If there are several key combinations to check, they need to be checked in a loop. You could create an array of the combinations or sth... I'll try play with this, and see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. I am trying to assign every combined keystroke into another language, so all I need it, just to store the combination you gave me, in a simple way

Comment: You sir, are one freaking genius. I couldn't have made a better script, if I learned js for many years. It is so simple, and so nice.

Comment: @kranzdot Thanks : ). I also tried to create a [backspace function](http://jsfiddle.net/aswgM/9/) for this, but it seems to be quite complex. Though I got `backspace` to work, it seems to be impossible to make a difference between replaced and non-replaced combinations when hitting `delete` on a selected text in `#in`. You maybe need to consider to replace the value of `#in` too...?

Comment: Thanks very much man, I actually added around the 200 letters and tried to create a backspace function, for hours litterally and finally just gave up. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here goes: If q has been pressed you got one second to get a 'w' otherwise you'll get an 'x'. Is this what you want? (Tried to make it as easy as possible to read, preferrably you'd refactor it a little :)

```
var openToW = false;

function check(e){
    var text = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

    if(text==81){
        openToW=true;
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML='q';
        setInterval(lock,1000);
    }
    if(text==87){
        if(!openToW){
            document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = 'x';
            return;
        }
        else{
           document.getElementById("out").innerHTML='w';
        }
    }
}

function lock(){
    openToW=false;
}
```

Comment: You may want to replace `seInterval()` with `setTimeout()`. Now browser will crash if `q` is pressed several times :-(.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, would this code be suitable if I have over 200 characters I would like to change? and What about @Teemu is saying? this script will crash the browser if q is pressed several time?

Comment: @kranzdot Magnus' code begins a new interval loop every time when `q` is pressed, that consumes a lot of memory... I also doubt this will work at all when `setInterval()` is involved.

Comment: @Teemu check my response on your answer